# check folder permissions and write them into a google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I try to create a google script which should create as output some google sheet with the folder permissions, for all folders named in the selections and each subfolder and files within the folders.

I tried the following Google Script code:

```js
function checkFolderPermissions() {
  var folderIds = ['FolderID1', 'FolderID2', 'FolderID3']; // Enter here the IDs of the folders to be checked
  
  var results = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < folderIds.length; i++) {
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderIds[i]);
    var editors = folder.getEditors();
    
    while (editors.hasNext()) {
      var editor = editors.next();
      results.push({
        Folder: folder.getName(),
        Editor: editor.getEmail(),
        Role: 'Editor'
      });
    }
  }
  
  if (results.length > 0) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    sheet.clear();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 3).setValues([['Folder', 'Editor', 'Role']]);
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, results.length, 3).setValues(results.map(function(result) {
      return [result.Folder, result.Editor, result.Role];
    }));
    Logger.log('The write permissions were successfully checked and added to the Google Sheet.');
  } else {
    Logger.log('No write permissions were found for the specified folders.');
  }
}
```

When I run this code I get the following error message "editors.hasNext is not a function", see also this screenshot:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6e1h.jpg)

The question has anybody an idea what is wrong here?

Or is there maybe some better standard solution availible to check folder permissions and write some overview into a google sheet?

Kind regards

Michael

1. explanation for the error message ""editors.hasNext is not a function" and how it can be solved
2. Is there some standard solution / script availible to check folder permissions and write some overview into a google sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- `getEditors()` of Class Folder returns User[]. I think that this is the reason for your current issue of `editors.hasNext is not a function`.

  - I think that this is the answer to your 1st question `explanation for the error message ""editors.hasNext is not a function" and how it can be solved`.
- I think that the header `['Folder', 'Editor', 'Role']` can be included in one `setValues` of `results.map(,,,`.
- About `for all folders named in the selections and each subfolder and files within the folders.`, in your script, the subfolders are not checked.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows. I think that this modified script might be the answer to your 2nd question `Is there some standard solution / script availible to check folder permissions and write some overview into a google sheet?`.

#### Modified script:

```js
function checkFolderPermissions() {
  var folderIds = ['FolderID1', 'FolderID2', 'FolderID3']; // Enter here the IDs of the folders to be checked

  var getSubFolders_ = (folder, values = []) => {
    if (folder) {
      var editors = folder.getEditors();
      if (editors.length > 0) {
        var folderName = folder.getName();
        editors.forEach(editor => values.push([folderName, editor.getEmail(), 'Editor']));
      }
      var subFolders = folder.getFolders();
      while (subFolders.hasNext()) {
        getSubFolders_(subFolders.next(), values);
      }
    }
    return values;
  }
  var results = folderIds.flatMap(id => getSubFolders_(DriveApp.getFolderById(id)));
  if (results.length > 0) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    sheet.clear();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, results.length + 1, 3).setValues([['Folder', 'Editor', 'Role'], ...results]);
    Logger.log('The write permissions were successfully checked and added to the Google Sheet.');
  } else {
    Logger.log('No write permissions were found for the specified folders.');
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, the subfolders in each folder of folder IDs are searched and an array `results` including editors are created. And, the array is put into the active sheet.

#### Note:

- In this modification, from your showing script and question, only editors of folders are retrieved. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [getEditors() of Class Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#geteditors)